# intentService thread not getting stopped permanently

Tags: android, android-service, intentservice, togglebutton, timertask

Even after googling for long, I couldn't find the solution to my problem.

Problem is:

In my application, I launch an intent which call the file implementing intentService on click of toggle button and runs it at regular interval since `startService()` is inside the timertask.
Now when I click on toggle button again, it stops the intent which it is supposed to do. But now the next time without closing the application when I click on toggle button again (start again) then it start 3 threads of intents instead of only new one.

I am not able to figure out what could be the reason and how can i solve it, Any help would be highly appreciable

Answer (score 0):

Ok so finally, I figured out what the problem was.
I just added a command

timer.cancel

on click of toggle button to stop the process and it worked like a charm.
Thanks